EAS creating DEBUG builds
I am building an expo react native application, and I am using eas to generate builds and submit the builts to the testflight and app store. Both the android and ios apps are prebuilt, hence I have android and ios native folders separately in my source code. However I noticed in the fastlane step, it's a log, which says
› Generating debug TestApp/TestApp-Production » TestApp.app.dSYM

I have also configured flavors for the application. The above line is pretty confusing to me because I am not sure why it's creating debug version.
But on the other hand I also find my configuration has been set for Release
| scheme                | TestApp-Production                                                                                                                                |
| configuration         | Release     


$ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./TestApp.xcworkspace -scheme TestApp-Production -configuration Release
▸ Command line invocation:
▸     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./TestApp.xcworkspace -scheme TestApp-Production -configuration Release
▸ User defaults from command line:
▸     IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
▸ resolved source packages:
$ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./TestApp.xcworkspace -scheme TestApp-Production -configuration Release 2>&1

I have the below configuration setup in my eas.json
 "production": {
      "distribution": "store",
      "credentialsSource": "remote",
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Release",
        "scheme": "TestApp-Production"
      }
    }

I am confused whats actually happening in fastlane. Is there a way to inspect the ipa generated from EAS and see whether is it a debug or a release variant? Does testflight allows debug variants to be published? Is this the usual way of things in eas?

Can I know why this is downvoted?
